# Can't get UITableView list to scroll in iPhone simulator

Tags: iphone, uitableview, scroll, ios-simulator

Is there a simple explanation for why a table will not scroll in the iPhone simulator? I have a tab bar application that I built with the standard template. I created a UITableView in the second tab controller. I initialized the objects with a list of items and they display nicely. However, neither the up/down arrow buttons work nor does the scroll. The rows can be highlighted.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried clicking on it with the mouse/trackpad, holding down, and dragging the mouse/trackpad up or down?  The simulator acts as it it's a real device and expects touch events.  It won't respond to the scroll of the mouse/trackpad since those aren't features found on the device

Comment: Well, that is a simple and perfect explanation - it worked. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should try to hold by clicking on table cell row and drag it up or down to move it

I am not able to understand the actual problem but follow the below link to know more about
     Tabbarcontroller and TableView :

http://iphonebyradix.blogspot.com/2010/12/uitabbarcontroller-overview.html

http://iphonebyradix.blogspot.com/2010/10/uitableview.html

Answer (score 3):

I think you should click on a cell, hold the mouse, and drag the mouse up or down. That action acts like a finger tap.

Answer (score 2):

Strange new one for me on a new forcetouch Macbook Pro...
`Hardware -> Touch Pressure -> Use Trackpad Force` I turned that off because my scrolling was being interrupted by Force Touches.... I had no idea what was going on.

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 fingers to drag and then scroll, it should work.

Comment: When you run iOS App on Mac (macOS Catalina version 10.15.5) you must use 2 fingers to scroll the TableView. It is absolute correct this answer. I have checked.